# my Internet email client (such as Hotmail) doesn't receive SMTP sent from my new Azure Windows 2012 server VM Visual Basic 2010 app

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, email, azure, smtp

My VisualBasic app on Azure Windows VM sends out email to an Internet email address by writing the email file to:
"C:\inetpub\mailroot\Pickup\

Wireshark running on Azure shows the SMTP outbound email, particularly this error message:
SMTP    356 S: 550 DY-001 (SNT004-MC4F36) Unfortunately, messages from 137.135.42.161 weren't sent.

But in
C:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail\
 I get .BAD messages From: postmaster@
"Delivery to the following recipients has been delayed"

WIRESHARK FULL CAPTURE DETAILS:
191 6.395954    65.55.33.135    100.112.82.73   SMTP    294 S: 220 COL004-MC6F25.hotmail.com Sending unsolicited commercial or bulk e-mail to Microsoft's computer network is prohibited. Other restrictions are found at http://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/anti-spam.mspx. Fri, 27 Nov 2015 05:48:13 -0800

192 6.396030    100.112.82.73   65.55.33.135    SMTP    69  C: EHLO

194 6.418826    65.55.33.135    100.112.82.73   SMTP    254 S: 250 COL004-MC6F25.hotmail.com (3.21.0.222) Hello [137.135.42.161] | 250 SIZE 36909875 | 250 PIPELINING | 250 8bitmime | 250 BINARYMIME | 250 CHUNKING | 250 STARTTLS | 250 AUTH LOGIN | 250 AUTH=LOGIN | 250 OK

195 6.418926    100.112.82.73   65.55.33.135    SMTP    98  C: MAIL FROM: SIZE=417

196 6.441695    65.55.33.135    100.112.82.73   SMTP    356 S: 550 DY-001 (COL004-MC6F25) Unfortunately, messages from 137.135.42.161 weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider. You can tell them that Hotmail does not relay dynamically-assigned IP ranges. You can also refer your provider to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors.

199 6.607452    100.112.82.73   65.55.33.135    SMTP    60  C: QUIT

Answer (score 0):

The message is a true one, this could be a serious risk for spammers to setup many VMs and spam away. You can try to get a reserved IP and see if that is blocked (I'm not sure off the top of my head if they are or are not)

http://michaelwasham.com/windows-azure-powershell-reference-guide/using-reserved-ip-addresses-with-microsoft-azure-virtual-machines/

Also consider alternate methods of sending emails, like another mail relay at a fixed IP location you fwd mail to.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/adoption-program-insights-sending-emails-from-windows-azure-part-1-of-2/

Lastly, there are third parties like SendGrid that allow you to send from Azure. There's a handful of options here, but sending from your server on a dynamic IP address which can change if you shut down/deallocate VM and turn it back on, shouldn't be considered one of them.